# Symfony only showing "symfony has been installed" on remote server

Tags: php, symfony, routes, server, hosting

So, school has given me this domain which includes quite a lot of program possibilities including symfony, I decided to try and get my website, made in symfony on there, but I can't get the routing to work since it only shows me a message saying that symfony has been installed successfully, I've ran out of options myself, I haven't tried a lot, since I don't know a lot about it, hence the question here.

TL:DR
Symfony only shows the "installed successfully" on remote server (hosted by Neostrada) I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

EDIT: here's a screenshot of the message:

[image: symfony message]

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of what's being shown. It's a different scenario if you're seeing a 'normal' symfony "Great, you installed me" index screen, or some custom host message. I could try to brief you out on how things are done afterwards with routing.

Comment: @NemanjaT I've added the screenshot you asked for, I hope you can walk me through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll post this link [here...](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html)
**read the note at the end of the answer first**

Now. I don't know if you know what MVC is, but shortly, it's a structure called Model-View-Controller where the user first contacts the Controller, in symfony also called an Action, which picks an appropriate action function, geatheres Models (via communicating with the database and all that magic) and then sends the whole package to the View (in symfony created in Twig templating framework).

The file structure is made like so:

```
app //contains main server files
 - cache //contains production and dev files, you won't pay much attention to this.
 - config //This is where you find the routing.yml, paremeters.yml and other config files
 - logs //git logs and other goodies
 - Resources //This is where your views are found
bin //Doctrine and goodies, don't pay much attention here for now...
src //This is where the bundles (controllers) are found
 - AppBundle //You should get this bundle by default
    - Controller //This is where you put your controllers - they have to have a Controller.php sufix (UserController.php)
    - Models, Enteties and other folders you want to put in //All custom folders
 - YourCustomBundle (note that both are ending with Bundle)
web //This is where you put your css, js etc. files (in js/, css/... subfolders)
```

Now, if you go to the `HomeController` in `src/AppBundle/Controller`. In there you'll see `indexAction` function. This one triggers the main, index page.

Note the namespace, usings and what the controller class is extending. If you create another action called, for instance `myCustomAction(Request $request)`, you'll create an action ready to take in orders. But from where? Go to `app/config/routing.yml`, you'll probably see something like:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Above it add:

```
page:
    path:     "/"
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Home:myCustom } 
//note that I first called the bundle (AppBundle, then the HomeController (without the 
//Controller part), then the action (no Action part neither)
```

Now you got yourself a path to your action! Now simply return a view in the controller (look at the indexAction), should be something like:

```
$this->render('home/mycustom.html.twig');
```

in the myCustomAction function. After that create a `mycustom.html.twig` file in the `app/Resources/views/home/` folder and that's your view. Note that Twig has a bit different syntax than PHP.

**note**: I highly suggest you learn from the official symfony website. This is all TL/DR (too long, didn't read) style of writing. It's explained a lot better there with details into *why* you're doing something. What I wrote might or might not work for you, because of the speed in which I explained the concept! Also if you're not familiar with MVC, I suggest you learn the logic behind it first, before rushing into Symfony.

Comment: First, thanks for your quick reply, although it's not what I'm looking for, I've done the things you instructed I'd do, and I had already read and followed the link several times, worked with MVC before, and my teacher challenged me to start working with symfony.

To get to the point, it's still showing the same message as in the screenshot above

Comment: @MikeDonkers Ah, I see, alright in the console write down `php app/console cache:clear --prod=dev` and then start the server again, the cache has to be cleared when major changes are made like this! :)